# Character comparision in java

Tags: java

I have an array of strings.
I need to find the position of the first capital character in each string.

How can I do it ?
Can someone give me a sample code for that in java?

```
import java.util.*; 
public class IPLRank { 
    public int n=0;
    private Scanner sc; 
    public void ranks(){ 
        sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Enter number of teams"); 
        n = sc.nextInt(); 
        char teams[][] = new char [n][50]; 
        System.out.println("Enter teams"); 
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){ 
            for (int j=0; j<50; j++) 
                teams[i][j] = sc.next().charAt(0); 
        } 
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){ 
            for (int j=0; j<50; j++) 
                System.out.println("Teams are "+teams[i][j]); 
            } 
        } 
    public static void main(String args[]){ 
        IPLRank r = new IPLRank(); r.ranks(); 
    }
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) besides asking us? Please show us what you have tried. SO is not a "Please do my work" site.

Comment: Why would you use `char[][]` instead of the much easier to work with `String[]`?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
for (String s : arrayOfStrings) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(i)) {
            System.out.println("First capital letter of string " + i + " is: " + s.charAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To find the index of the first capital letter, you can iterate through the char array of the string and use Character.isUppercase(Char c) method

```
public int firstUpperCaseIndex(String str) {        
    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
        if(Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(i))) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: does this iterate through the string array?

Comment: No, it doesn't. But you should split up the code to small method like this to enhance readability.

Answer (score 2):

65 to 90 is the ascii code range for capital letters.

See here. http://www.ascii-code.com/

So here's the method for you.

```
public static int getFirstCapitalCharacterPosition(String x) {
    for(int i=0; i< x.length(); i++) {
        int val = x.charAt(i);
        if(val >= 65 && val <=90) {
          return i;  
        }
    } 
    return -1;
}

public static void main(String [] args) {
    String array = {"teSt","Test", "tesT"};
    for(String x : array) {
        System.out.println(getFirstCapitalCharacterPosition(x));
    }  
}
```

Comment: how can i run this for a string array?

Answer (score 0):

I could recommend you to look at the ASCII table. It will solve your problem probably.